# Angular 12 and source-map-explorer: Source-map-explorer showing "no source" for a 16% chunk

Tags: angular, build, bundle, source-maps

while working on an Angular 12 application with PrimeNg, I have come across a peculiar scenario. When I generate a build and try to check the bundles with source-map-explorer (we are not using web-pack), I see a 16% chunk saying "no source":
[image]

Can someone tell me from where this chunk is coming? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, this "no source" chunk was found to be coming from PrimeNg library. As such, we cannot do anything about it right now.